# highly technical skills: is it possible for uni staff to provide these skills for a thesis or must you teach your self?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, thesis, university, research-undergraduate

*Note, by highly technical skills I mean anything that isn't directly taught by your course (i.e. programming/coding, use of specialist lab equipment, mathematical expertise)*

I am student of Earth Sciences/Geography within the UK.

I'm planning on doing a masters and in brainstorming ideas for my application's thesis proposal, I often run up against the issue of lacking specific technical skills needed to conduct the study. Should I let this hamper me? **I worry I'm restricting my potential by only choosing topics in which I can wholly conduct every step of the research/analysis independently.**

For example, my undergraduate dissertation required large datasets and modifying open-source software, meaning I independently taught my self to code. Another student looked at microfossils which required the use of a spectrometer.

Although both of skills were not taught to us, I independently taught my self to code while uni staff operated the spectrometer machine for my peer, meaning he didn't have to learn it.

If I want to study, say, microplastics in fish, will I need to be able know how to use the required lab equipment and interpret the results or is it acceptable to outsource this?

### Summary

To word my question another way, **University thesis: How can you utilise highly technical skills without falling into the rut of teaching your self everything from scratch?**

**I taught my self coding for the sake of my undergraduate dissertation, at the cost of a loss of free time which could be spent on my area of study (Earth Science, not Computer Science). Coding is not the direction I want to take in life despite the effort to learn it. I, therefore, do not want to invest so heavily in another one-off skill for my masters.**

My two main concerns are:

- Restricting my potential research topics to studies which I can wholly conduct and interpret each research technique.
- Become stuck teaching my self a skill which I do not desire to follow up in the future (i.e. a statistical technique, coding, lab equip)
- Use up a lot of time independently learning said technique

### Real life example

In the question linked [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/how-to-speak-to-advisor-about-hiring-an-unscrupulous-student?rq=1), a SE user discusses how during his masters two programmers were hired to help with programming. Would it be reasonable to request the university for someone to help with a skill I've not been taught (i.e. coding or high-level statistics) for my master's thesis?

Comment: Expensive experimental equipment will often be operated by staff. The purpose is not to make some student's lives easier, but instead to keep the equipment up and running for all users. Those students still spend their own time learning things too. Sorry, but your question comes off as a rant. If you learn a lot, you get to tell future employers (or potential advisors) how you are a self starter who learned a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question "is it possible for staff to provide these skills" is not answerable here because it depends on the specific school.

Comment: @JonCuster. Apologies if it comes off as a rant. It's not something I feel negative about, it's just something which I'm seeking advice on in order to better place my productivity on where I want to improve. There's lots of skills out there to learn and I believe it's best to devote most time to those which will serve you most in later life and potential career path, if possible, or else you can end up learning plenty and doing little.

Comment: @MadJack Understood. I just mean it in a general sense for university level research, not specific skills, but I take your point. Should I re-word it?

Comment: Perhaps you could reword the question to focus on what is common with respect to who is supposed to run the key pieces of equipment, etc. for students in your field (you could also update your question with your field; where in the world you are could be important, too).

Comment: Thanks. Edited to provide a bit more background as well as a real life example.

Comment: I'm slightly offended by the suggestion that coding is a "one-off skill" as opposed to a fundamental prerequisite for modern science, like reading, typing, or basic statistics.

Comment: _but not a prerequisite for an every individual to be a great scientist_ — If you say so.

Comment: @JeffE Wow, yes, so much yes. To the OP: a huge part of the value of academic education is picking up these sorts of skills. Work on a project you are interested in: all of the skills related are by definition related to what you are interested in and therefore relevant for the future.

Comment: Your original post said: "If I want to study, say, microplastics in fish, will I need to be able know how to use the required lab equipment and interpret the results or is it acceptable to outsource this?" - yes you have to do this. When people are hiring programmers or statisticians, its usually whole research groups rather than a programmer assigned to an individual master's student - that's an entirely different circumstance.

Comment: And I don't think you sound like a slacker, I think you just sound very naive if you think coding (or statistics) is a one-off skill, for the same reasons that @JeffE pointed out.

Comment: @BryanKrause and JeffE: in some fields coding can be surely considered a one-off skill. Imagine that you are a physicists and for a certain experiment you need a specialized amplifier: will you spend years learning how to design high-performance amplifiers just for one  or two experiments? Certainly not. Well, in some fields programming is exactly like that.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I am not (nor is JeffE, by my understanding) suggesting that it is necessary to know every specialized technique (i.e., you don't need to program a new unix-based OS to use one), rather that programming is a highly flexible skill that can come up in unexpected places in a career, it doesn't belong in a "one-off" category. There's also a big difference between needing to *use* a specialized amplifier(or software) versus *build* one. If you need to use it, you have to learn to use it, not necessarily how to build it.

Comment: @BryanKrause Being able to code is exactly like being able to build circuits, just in different fields (and depending on the application being able to do the latter can be much more useful than being able to do the former). Anyway, the purpose of my remark is just to highlight that each person judges the importance of certain skills depending on their background, and if one doesn't know all the details it's better to avoid contending certain claims so strongly (that said, I'm certainly one who encourages people to enlarge as much as possible their working toolbox).

Comment: @user3200293 you mention you want to devote time to skills which will help your career, so it might be useful to know what career you would be interested in pursuing once you have finished your Masters (to be honest, even if you are not planning to stay in academia, I am inclined to agree with Jeff et al- learning to code is a valuable investment for your future and programming skills are sought by employers in all fields).

Comment: @user3300293 sounds like doing sci comm or outreach might be good options for you, or even working for an educational charity. In this case I would be conservative with a research proposal and limit yourself to achievable goals (if you're not planning on a research career then the content of the project is less important than gaining a good degree).

Comment: I've considered sci comm and charities, but I always feel that doing a job with a higher wage or higher influence (even if it's not related to a charity) can give you a greater ability to help. For example, I know someone who completed a chemistry PHD at Oxford and wishes his friend's children approach him for advice before making life choices, as he is in contact with company directors and thus could help obtain internships. This type of influence I think a charity worker would struggle to wield. Thanks for your thought out and informative replies Astronaut.

Comment: p.s. Aber was my first choice, though I opted for somewhere else in Wales a little more easy to reach with less flooding!

Comment: @user3200293 not Bangor I hope ;)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is very simple. If doing your research requires coding, **you will have to learn how to code**. Period. You can teach yourself, or take a class, or hire a tutor or whatever, but one way or another, you won't get very far trying to get your university, or anyone else, do the coding for you. As @JeffE and others were politely trying to help you understand, coding in the science and technology worlds today is such a basic skill that your comparison to operating specialized lab equipment simply isn't appropriate. A more proper comparison would be to things like typing up documents or using Microsoft Excel. Would you consider asking your university to get someone to help you with Excel because you can't be bothered to learn it? No? Didn't think so...

As for other skills which your question might be applied to, I think the answer would be *it depends*, but it seems pretty clear you are mainly interested in coding.

Comment: I downvoted this answer for the reasons outlined in my comments below the question. I'm sure that you wouldn't have objected if instead of coding the OP asked about being able to use a lathe, and you'd have said go to a workshop.

Comment: Depending on how much coding(or whatever is needed) is involved and how difficult the problems are it's also quite common and very reasonable to get people involved which are experts on whatever you need. We got several collaboration partners who do things we could technically do ourselves but they got much better equipment and knowledge so it would be stupid to not do it this way.

Comment: @Massimo you are correct, I don't see coding and using a lathe as analogous in this respect. Your hypothetical scenario where OP has chosen to work in a field where he/she will only need coding skills for one project in their entire career is simply not realistic. If they are on a STEM career path and their research project involves some coding, my premise is that it is essentially certain that future projects they will be involved in (either in academia or in industry) will also require at least basic familiarity and proficiency with coding. As others have said, _it is not a one-off skill_.

Answer (score 4):

Having just finished my Master's in a subject area in which I had very little technical expertise before starting, I hope I can provide a reasonable answer. (My project involved some mathematics and statistics which were new to me before starting, as well as learning a new programming language from scratch.)

> I'm planning on doing a masters and in brainstorming ideas for my
>   application's thesis proposal, I often run up against the issue of
>   lacking specific technical skills needed to conduct the study. **Should
>   I let this hamper me?** I worry I'm restricting my potential by only
>   choosing topics in which I can wholly conduct every step of the
>   research/analysis independently.

I think the key here is working out which skills you can reasonably expect to learn during the project and do a sort of cost/ benefit analysis. You need to be realistic about what is feasible. If the barrier is a particular statistical technique that you're unfamiliar with, it may be relatively easy to pick it up as you go along- you may even understand it better by using it "in real life".

However, if the skill is much more difficult, for example, learning to program if you've never typed a line of code in your life before, then it is probably unrealistic to plan a study using such a skill. This comes down to your judgement and your judgement alone; we don't know how easy or difficult such skills may be for you to learn.

> To word my question another way (...) how can you
>   utilise highly technical skills without falling into the rut of
>   teaching your self everything from scratch?

In my own (small) research experience, I found that learning tools on the job actually meant I learnt more, and faster than if I had taken a course on it. I learnt more about programming by teaching myself to write code in Python than I got from two years of lectures and workshops on Fortran during my undergraduate. And you know what, I also enjoyed it more! Learning is fun-- but the most valuable part was that I learnt how to teach myself skills. I started to learn how to be an independent academic. And if you want to do any kind of academic research in the future, knowing how to learn independently is important. In fact, I'd argue that's the whole point of the degree.

> Would it be reasonable to request the university for someone to help
>   with a skill I've not been taught (i.e. coding or high-level
>   statistics) for my master's thesis?

As Mad Jack says, this depends on the individual department/ university, but I think you are underestimating the help your supervisor will likely provide. If the skills or techniques are common in the field, they will help you learn them (or point you in the direction of a friendly PhD/ post doc who can).

Ultimately research is all about learning new things. You never know, the skills you learn now might seem useless, but in ten years' time may be vital to your research. I don't think you can get stuck in a rut when you have the whole world around you to learn more about.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but my impression from the OP wasn't that they wanted their advisor to help them learn techniques, rather they are wondering if the university will provide them people to do parts of their research for them.

Comment: @Bryan, indeed, but I think the answer to that question is simply no, they won't (unless, as pointed out by Jon Custer, they need to operate expensive, university owned equipment).